# Ruby and .irbrc : Find whether a method is defined.

Tags: ruby, irb

I have a function in my .irbrc which basically builds together a string form certain input parameters, and then is supposed to check, whether another function with name of this string exists. I'm doing it like this

```
methodname = ... # Calculate a string
if respond_to?(methodname)
  ....
end
```

This does not work in that respond_to? returns false even in those cases where in my opinion it should return true. I have boiled down the problem to the following simple case:

I have in my .irbrc

```
def foo
end
def respond_to_foo?
  respond_to?(:foo)
end
puts "Respond: #{respond_to_foo?}"
```

Running `irb`, this outputs *false*. I would expect it to print *true* instead. Still, I am able to run `foo` from within irb.

I guess that this has to do with the scope in which irb defines my methods. For instance, `self.foo` does not work (*private method 'foo' called for main:Object*), while `send.foo` does work (since it bypasses privacy). This looks like a clue to my problem, but I still can't come up with an explanation, nor find the proper way for doing my task.

Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: FWIW: in [`pry`](http://pryrepl.org/) it perfectly works as expected. Would you mind to try `methods.grep(/foo/)` to see if the method is indeed defined?

Comment: The method is defined (after all, I can call it), but we can't see it with the command you suggested. But I found a way to fix it. See my own answer to this problem. Maybe `pry` has a different approach how to handle the interactive shell.

Comment: Here is a clue (but I cannot explain it): `respond_to_foo? #=> false` when the code is in irbrc, `respond_to_foo? #=> true` when executed in an IRB session. (Ruby v2.5.1)

Comment: Oddly enough, change the foo definition to `def self.foo; end;` and it all works.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: It just occured to me, that I could use

```
private_methods.include?(:foo)
```

This does work, but it looks a bit like a hack to me. If someone knows a better way, please let me know.